# Implement PATCH operation Play - Java

Tags: java, json, hibernate, playframework, uri

I have to update my resources partially using `PATCH`request whose body is a `JSON`. Below is my POJO for OwnerDetails. I am using play-framework with Hibernate.

```
public class OwnerDetailsVO {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I have created rows in MySQL for the Entity Object which corresponds to this value object (VO).

My `JSON` body for `PATCH` request is,

```
PATCH /owners/123

[
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/name", "value": "new name" }
]
```

I have configured the correct route to the method in the routes file.

Here is the `OwnerController` class which should process the `JSON` request. I am using POSTMAN to send the requests.

```
public class OwnerController extends Controller {

   public Result create() {
     Form<OwnerDetailsVO> odVOForm = Form.form(OwnerDetailsVO.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(odVOForm.hasErrors()) {
            return jsonResult(badRequest(odVOForm.errorsAsJson()));
        }

        OwnerDetailsVO odVO = odVOForm.get();
        int id = odProcessor.addOwnerDetails(odVO);

        return jsonResult(ok(Json.toJson("Successfully created owner account with ID: " + id)));
   }

   public Result update(int id) {
      //I am not sure how to capture the data here.
      //I use Form to create a new VO object in the create() method

   }
}
```

How should the request be captured inside the `update()` function so that I can partially update my resource? I am not able to find good documentations to know about `PATCH` operations for Play! Framework.

Edit: I have seen about WSRequest for Patch operation, but I am not sure how to use that. Will that be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code using ebeans in Play Framework

```
    public Item patch(Long id, JsonNode json) {

    //find the store item
    Item item = Item.find.byId(id);
    if(item == null) {
        return null;
    }

    //convert json to update item
    Item updateItem;
    updateItem = Json.fromJson(json, Item.class);


    if(updateItem.name != null){
        item.name = updateItem.name;
    }
    if(updateItem.price != null){
        item.price = updateItem.price;
    }
    item.save();

    return item;
}
```

Comment: Not working. I am getting `JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of` exception. How can the PATCH request be converted to `Item` type?